# How to get HTML element to pop up in google sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I want a specific cell in my google sheets to read from the CNBC website. Specifically, I want the price of the stock from this page: https://www.cnbc.com/quotes/DDOG?tab=news

I'm following a guide that tells me that I need to use the IMPORTXML function. I do that however, when I copy the class from DevTools, I get this error: `formula parse error`

Here's the function I'm trying to enter:

```
=IMPORTXML("=IMPORTXML("https://www.cnbc.com/quotes/DDOG?tab=news","//*[@id="quote-page-strip"]/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/span[1]")
```

I'm getting a `formula parse error` but was expecting to see the stock ticker for the given element pop up on my google sheets cell.

Answer (score 1):

You may try:

```
=index(importxml("https://www.cnbc.com/quotes/DDOG?tab=news","//div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]"),1)
```

[image]

Comment: This is working. Thanks so much, why do we need to put an "=index?" in front of the function?

Comment: This specific xpath is giving out result in 2 cells as `68.75 +1.91 (+2.86%)`; so restricted it to one cell of `68.75` using index function.